# Definition fl.controls:Label could not be found

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashdevelop

I'm using ActionScript 3.  Developing in FlashDevelop. I get the following error when I try to do `import fl.controls.Label;`

```
Definition fl.controls:Label could not be found.
```

I'm pretty new to Flash. I had this project working without a glitch. I must have changed something for it to stop recognizing the import. Even *Intellisense* gives me an option to add `fl.controls.Label`

Answer (score 10):

Controls in the fl.controls namespace are native to Flash Professional.

Although I don't use Flash Develop, this is similar to Flash Builder.

If you had Flash Pro you could create a library of components, then export a SWC library for use in your Flash Develop project.  Or, reference Flash Pro's controls.

If this previously worked in your project, perhaps your compiler settings no longer link a required SWC dependency?

Not sure if this will help, but I would follow this in Flash Builder:

**Flash Components:**

**Adding by SWC:**

- Right-click on your project in Flash Builder, and go to Properties.
- Select "ActionScript Build Path" from the left.
- Go to the "Libary path" tab now available on the right.
- Click "Add SWC..."
- Add libs from Flash such as flash.swc or IK, depending on what version of the Flash IDE you have and where you installed it.

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\libs\flash.swc

**Adding by source folder:**

- Right-click on your project in Flash Builder, and go to Properties.
- Select "ActionScript Build Path" from the left.
- Go to the "Source path" tab now available on the right.
- Click "Add Folder..."
- The Flash components should be in a location with a path similar to the following, depending on what version of the Flash IDE you have and where you installed it.

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5.5\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface

  ...or...

  C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\Configuration\Component Source\ActionScript 3.0\User Interface

**Default playerglobal namespace.**

Default package / playerglobal.swc reference often is incorrect when editing from Flash in Flash Builder.

In .actionScriptProperties, add:

```
<libraryPathEntry kind="3" linkType="1" path="${FLASHPRO_APPCONFIG}/ActionScript 3.0/FP10.2/playerglobal.swc" useDefaultLinkType="false"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need general fl.* libraries, copy this swc:

```
/Applications/Adobe Flash CS6/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/libs/flash.swc
```

Into your Flash Builder project using these steps:

[image: Adding a swc to Flash Builder]