# FLVPlayback without Flash CS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flvplayback

I'm implementing Google video Ads in flash game, using FlashDevelop. Google has a sample where they're using FLVPlayback component to display video... problem is, I don't have this class anywhere.

I've searched how to add it, but all solutions say "link to C:\Adobe\Flash CS\Components\etc" path, which obiouvsly without Flash CS I don't have... and don't want to install it just for this :)

I wonder if there is a way to get the FLVPlayback without installing Flash CS?

Comment: Why not just use the Video class? (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html)

Comment: I do it in order to display Google video ads, and they need to have some event listeners attached, ie. TimeEvent.COMPLETE and TimeEvent.CURRENT_TIME_CHANGE. I don't see a way in this Video class to do that... but thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quit and just installed the Flash Professional CC, and there linked to the component path, but it didn't work for some reason. Then I included the FLVPlayback.swf component inside my AS3 app, which compiled etc. but as I learned FLVPlayback wasn't really what I needed.

After some fumbling I made it work with Flex Spark component - VideoPlayer, used inside AS3. You can find some code on the devlist: https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/community?place=msg%2Fima-sdk%2Fc3KH11vxSd0%2FeLuYneYpch4J

Answer (score 1):

You can try import external adobe components swc through Flashdevelop interface.

Maybe this can help you: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492754/definition-fl-controlslabel-could-not-be-found)